# Which programming language performs this task?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm looking to dynamically display information based on an input field search. Problem is, I'm not sure what language to use. I guess I'd better show what I am looking to do first off (sorry I'm making you watch a video, but it's the best representation of what I'm looking for): https://new.myspace.com/play (about 1:05 into the video, the 'Justin Timberlake' search)

So I was thinking that maybe it was AJAX, but as far as I know AJAX doesn't dynamically display content like that. Normally AJAX allows an input search and guesses what you are trying to say while you're typing.

Then I figured it might be PHP, but once again, I figured it might not be PHP because there is no 'submit' before the content appears which leads me to believe that it isn't PHP because there is no 'POST' or 'GET' being activated.

lastly, wasn't sure if it was javascript/jquery where the information is hidden and displayed only when the input field contains the same string as some of the content on the page.

Anyhow, just wondering what kind of language does this, so I can get the ball rolling on figuring out how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: AJAX is not a programming language

Comment: Read this: **it's all of them**. It's AJAX which is done in javascript (there's no other way), it's DOM manipulation done in javascript (there's no other way), it's ALSO a server-side language (like PHP, there's no other way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are aiming at building a website that dynamically changes content whenever an input field is edited, your language of choice for making the user interface part happen is Javascript.

That said, you are probably looking at a more complex problem because the Javascript part needs to retrieve its information from a source which usually is not static so you would also build a backend that uses the contents of the input tag and returns suitable results for the string contained in it - for that, more or less any language works, common choices would be PHP, Ruby, Python.. etc.pp. for a web service architecture.

Comment: And AJAX is the mechanism used to get the data from the backend into the browser.

Comment: AJAX is an acronym for Asynchronous Javascript And XML.

Comment: These days it's more often `AJAJ` J - *...and JSON*. But AJAX has the buzzword power.

Comment: Thank you Henrik, I appreciate the help. More help than someone just telling me that AJAX itself isn't a programming language (which I was already aware of, I just didn't specify that it wasn't.) Also thanks Flavius for the added help.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is a general purpose mechanism that can be used for many different things. Any time a web page updates dynamically, it's most likely JavaScript using AJAX.

jQuery is one of many libraries that makes writing JavaScript easier. There's no way to tell from the effect whether it's actually being used.

Comment: Just to emphasize: "Javascript **using** AJAX".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really like to do, but since you're thinking about using PHP, Javascript, AJAX, or JQuery, the answer i would give is PHP.

Using PHP, you can use combination of javascript, ajax, jquery, html, etc. or any other library to do a certain process.

About ajax, is use intentionaly to avoid reloading of page.

About php, using this with combination of ajax, you might think that theres no POST or GET being activated in a page as it process

About jquery, theres a lot of things jquery can do.